# poll implemenation on linux vs poll implementation on solaris

Tags: c, linux, solaris

During debugging our application in linux enviroment we can observe that some events - `POLLHUP|POLLIN` occur only on linux. Our application uses unix sockets. When we do:

```
ret = poll(xpoll->pfd, xpoll->pfd_count, xpoll_timeout);
```

strace shows:

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 3, 16) = 1 
([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
```

That situation never occurs in solaris (same application):
struss shows:

```
2463/3:                 fd=569 ev=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP rev=0
2463/3:                 fd=639 ev=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP rev=0
2463/3:                 fd=631 ev=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP rev=POLLIN
2463/3:                 fd=1160 ev=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP rev=0
2463/3:                 fd=400 ev=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP rev=0
```

Can You please explain me what is the difference between poll in solaris and poll in liunx ?
Thx in advance for all answers.

Comment: Linux returns POLLIN (data to read) even in case of EOF.
Linux there is no POLLEOF flag. 
That is all I now about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both, Linux and Solaris, used to fail to set POLLIN for EOF on some types of files, especially pipes. A common workaround was checking for POLLHUP and POLLIN together.
As far as I know, the Linux core developers kept it that way (probably intended), whilst the Solaris fellows changed that behavior to use <strike>POLLIN</strike> POLLEOF.

However, this should be no issue for your application: In order to increase an application's portability, one would always check for both flags in the bit-mask.

Cheers!

Comment: BTW, since POLLEOF is not a part of POSIX - maybe it's an alias for another macro(-combination) like POLLIN or POLLIN|POLLHUP? I have to check that...